# LocalDate with JPA does not work correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I do request `localhost:8080/history/world/2020-02-08`

Entity:

```
public class DailyStatistic {
...
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate date;
...
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/world/{date}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DailyStatistic>> getWorldStatByDate(@PathVariable String date) {
        List<DailyStatistic> worldStatList = null;
        try {
            worldStatList = dataProvider.getWorldStatByDate(LocalDate.parse(date));
...
```

Invoked dataProvider method:

```
public List<DailyStatistic> getWorldStatByDate(LocalDate date) throws NoDataException {
        List<DailyStatistic> dailyStatisticList = repository.findAllByDate(date);
...
```

Invoked repository method:

```
 @Repository
public interface DailyStatRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyStatistic, Long> {

    List<DailyStatistic> findAllByDate(LocalDate date);
```

Json answer:

```
{
...
"date": "2020-02-07",
...
}
```

Remind input: `localhost:8080/history/world/2020-02-08`

So I get a wrong resultSet. Anybody knows why it happens and how it solve?

Comment: check timezone in your databaseurl

Comment: @Golam Mazid sajib thank you for answer) Does it matter? I use mysql with ?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false. What I need to change?

Comment: use your local timezone. serverTimezone=yourlocaltimezone

Comment: or convert your localdate timezone to utc then call query

Comment: @Golam Mazid sajib thank you, using local timezone helps) But would be work correctly, if I will deploy the service on heroku with heroku database?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way in your entity

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@JsonSerialize(converter = LocalDateTimeToStringConverter.class)
@JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalDatetimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime date;
```

[See this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-serialize-deserialize-converter.html)

Or simply this way

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date;
```

Comment: There was a problem with a timezone, good people helped to solve it. But now I got a problem with parsing, I think so. When I call -> List<DailyStatistic> findAllByCountryAndDateBetween(Country country, LocalDate from, LocalDate to);